# Localization CMS - Admin functionality to edit the localization files for Content Editors?

Tags: asp.net, localization

Are there solutions/tutorials/open source solutions to providing the functionality of having Content Editors edit ASP.net Localization files?

For example,

With Labels.resx and Labels.fr.resx, it would be great if theres an editor out there that allows End Users to end the content of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a database solution with caching.  I found this article which might help.  It has a complete provider along with a very good write up.

Creating a Data Driven ASP.NET Localization
Resource Provider and Editor

http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/wwDbResourceProvider/

> ASP.NET 2.0 introduces a provider
>   model for creating custom Resource
>   Providers that can store localization
>   data in stores other than Resx files.
>   Resx resources are all fine and good
>   but putting data in a more flexible
>   resource store gives you many more
>   options for editing and administering
>   resources interactively and even at
>   runtime. In this article I'll
>   demonstrate how to create a new
>   Resource Provider that stores resource
>   information in a database and show a
>   resource editing tool that makes it
>   much easier to edit resources
>   interactively in the context of your
>   live ASP.NET applications.

Particular bit to note:

> Resx Resources are also static – they
>   are after all compiled into an
>   assembly. If you want to make changes
>   to resources you will need to
>   recompile to see those changes.
>   ASP.NET 2.0 introduces Global and
>   Local Resources which can be stored on
>   the server and can be updated
>   dynamically – the ASP.NET compiler can
>   actually compile them at runtime.
>   However, if you use a precompiled Web
>   deployment model the resources still
>   end up being static and cannot be
>   changed at runtime. So once you’re
>   done with compilation the resources
>   are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote an application like that because I could not find a free soft that does *resx* editing:

- Reads the content of all the *resx* files from a folder
- Displays the values from different cultures but same *resx* besides each other
- Generates/saves the *resx* files back

Comment: Do you have source code available? I would love to review it when developing/customizing to fit the needs of the project I am working on

Comment: fell free to add the source code to all of us :) we will thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using structured XML files.  Seems like this would be a more elegant solution than hacking .resx files to work in an unconventional way.  You could use a LINQ query to get to the XML in a strongly typed manner similar to the resx file.  Additionally, XML files could be edited by the user through the presentation layer since they aren't compiled into the application.